# 2D array in Objective C From C#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array

My Code :

```
 float[2][] fSlvPipePtsC;

  fSlvPipePtsC[0] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
  fSlvPipePtsC[1] = CGPointMake(0, 1);
```

I am converting this code from C#. Please help me to achieve this is objective C?

Comment: Just a note, in C# that is not a 2-D array, but rather a jagged array (or array of arrays) . A 2-D array would look like `float[,]`. This doesn't answer your question, but the proper terminology might help you find an answer.

Comment: Also as someone with 6k rep, you should know that the implementation of `CGPointMake` may be pertinent to the answer. Likewise you may want to supply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did. Check following code.

```
 NSMutableArray *fSlvPipePtsC = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
CGPoint new1 = CGPointMake(5.5,10.0 );
        CGPoint new2 = CGPointMake(0.0, 11.0);

    [fSlvPipePtsC insertObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:new1] atIndex:0];
    [fSlvPipePtsC insertObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:new2] atIndex:1];
```

After i can use like following:

```
 CGPoint PointFp3 = CGPointMake([[fSlvPipePtsC objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].x, [[fSlvPipePtsC objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].y);
        CGPoint PointFp4 = CGPointMake([[fSlvPipePtsC objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue].x, [[fSlvPipePtsC objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue].y);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you want. You want an array of points? In Objective-C `NSArray`s can only contain objects, not scalar values.

If you want to create a C array of points, you could do that:

```
CGPoint[] pointArray;
int pointCount = 10;

pointArray = (CGPoint*) calloc(pointCount, sizeof(CGPoint));

pointArray[0] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
pointArray[1] = CGPointMake(0, 1);

//...

free((void*)pointArray);
```

If you do that then the burden is on you to not go beyond the bounds of the memory you allocate, and also to free the memory you allocate once you're done with it. Objective-C's ARC memory management does not cover objects you create with `malloc()`.

Alternately you can wrap CGPoint objects in an `NSValue`, and then you can store the `NSValue`s in an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableArray *pointArray = [NSMutableArray new];

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(2, 4);
NSValue *pointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
[pointArray append: pointValue];

//...

CGPoint somePoint = [pointArray[0] CGPointValue];
```

(Disclaimer: I work mostly in Swift these days, and my Objective-C is getting rusty. There might be syntax errors in the code above. It's intended as a guide, not code to be copy/pasted.)

Note that Swift is more like C#. You're free to create an array of CGPoint objects, append to it directly, etc. If you're coming from C#, you'll probably be happier learning Swift. Plus that's the direction in which the industry is headed, so you'd be better served learning Swift.